# spark bucketby number of files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I understand that the number of files = number of tasks ✕ number of buckets if I do `dataframe.bucketBy().saveAsTable()`, but that introduces too many small files. I also know that if I do `repartition("some column")` and then `bucketBy("some column")`, then the output file should be the same as the number of buckets. However, repartition is expensive and triggers shuffling.

Is there any way that I can avoid shuffle and get a small number of files?